# Keep focus inside iframe modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have a modal on my page but inside an iframe. I want to limit the tab focus inside the modal until the user click the accept button. The accept button is the last focusable element. I am using the following code but after focus out the focus goes outside the modal

```
modalAcceptButton.addEventListener('focusout', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    modalHeading.focus();
});
```

any suggestions?

**Solution idee**:

https://jsfiddle.net/momenelkamri/6q9fh2n0/

thanks to https://gist.github.com/gustavpursche/5907263